# about newcommand

Tags: macros, errors

I have trying to use new command to represent math, and this is what I type in:

```
\\
\newcommand\fpi2[2][\pi][2]{frac{#1}{#2}}\\
\newcommand\mylim[2][x]{lim_{#1\to #2}}
```

I'm trying to create a new command which represent `$frac{\pi}{2}$`
Is it possible for me to use `\mylim{${\fpi2}^-$}`?

Comment: Unless you use a `\csname ... \endcsname` workaround method, you can't have a non-letter (such as the numeral `2`) be part of a command name. Use a command name such as `\fpi` or `\fpitwo` instead.

Comment: You have posted several questions in the last few days repeating the same error every time: you need a backslash `\frac` and `\lim` not `frac` and `lim` (in addition to the point of this question that you can not have a command `\fpi2`.)

Answer (score 2):

The name of a command should contain only letters (not absolutely true, but at the moment let's accept it). Apparently your command doesn't require arguments, since you are interested in a constants string:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\fpi{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\newcommand\mylim[2][x]{\lim_{#1\to #2}}

\begin{document}

$\fpi\quad\mylim{\fpi^-}$

\[
\fpi\quad\mylim{\fpi^-}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HuangElizabeth You're welcome! Don't forget that (after a sensible wait) you can accept answers by clicking the checkmark to their left :-)